# Trying to 'call' stored procedures with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

i've this working code with CI:

```
$this->db->query("call nameOfProcedure('param1', @param2)");
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT @param2 as results');
$row = $query->row();
```

it works, but if I try to use:

```
$this->db->call_function('nameOfProcedure', 'param1', '@param2');
```

i get the error:

> This feature is not available for the database you are using.

What's wrong exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it helps anyone. I use this library to work with stored procedures in CI, it supports multiple result sets too.

here is the code

I call it `Mydb.php`

```
<?php #if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mydb
{
   private $CI, $Data, $mysqli, $ResultSet;

   /**
   * The constructor
   */

   function __construct()
   {
     $this->CI =& get_instance();
     $this->Data = '';
     $this->ResultSet = array();
     $this->mysqli = $this->CI->db->conn_id;
   }

    public function GetMultiResults($SqlCommand)
    {
    /* execute multi query */
    if (mysqli_multi_query($this->mysqli, $SqlCommand)) {
        $i=0;
        do
        {

             if ($result = $this->mysqli->store_result()) 
             {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $this->Data[$i][] = $row;
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
             }
            $i++; 
        }
        while ($this->mysqli->next_result());
    }
    return $this->Data;

   }   
}
?>
```

call it like this from controller

```
$this->load->library('mydb');
$arr  = $this->mydb->GetMultiResults("CALL GetReferrals()");
```

Also, make sure to set `mysqli` the driver
in `application/config/database.php`

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: The library ONLY supports to return multiple result sets, and if a procedure return one only result ret, will throw error.  To also support return one result return, must change the line "while ($this->mysqli->next_result());" to "while ($this->mysqli->more_results()&&$this->mysqli->next_result());".

Comment: @Stony its a do-while loop, did you test its not working?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html) on `call_function`.  It's for calling functions that aren't native to CI's DB driver, not for calling procedures you've written.

You can check the `call_function` code in `/system/database/DB_driver.php` Ln 998 on CI 2.1.0 to see clearly what it's doing.

Comment: Not sure why you didn't chose this answer as correct. The docs clearly state it's for calling **PHP** database functions. Nowhere does it mention stored procedures.