# Error : This feature is not available for the database you are using

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter

I am using oci8 as my database driver in Codeigniter.
While using the following code that calls a stored procedure gives me error :

```
$this->db->call_function('update_letter_body', $body_letter, $insert_id);

Error : This feature is not available for the database you are using.
```

What should be done to make this work ?

I am trying to set a value that has more than 4000 characters which doesn't seem to work from direct query and seems like the codeigniter does not support calling functions for oracle. Any suggestions ?

Comment: as far as i guess these functions are only available to work with mysql not with oracle

Comment: CI oci8 driver is not updated since long time i faced the same problem for my project

Comment: Are you sure `CodeIgniter` will not submit a 4000 character normal query using `$this->db->query()`, or maybe its just that your `max_post_size` or `max_execution_time` is set to low?

Comment: @StevenFarley : yeah, it does not, check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945710/error-ora-01704-string-literal-too-long

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046075/trying-to-call-stored-procedures-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hmmm , try with

```
$this->db->query("CALL update_letter_body(".$body_letter.",".$insert_id.")");
```

`call_function` **enables you to call PHP database functions that are not natively included in CodeIgniter,not for calling procedures you've written.**

check the documentation

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html