# How to fetch multiple results returned from stored procedure - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Im able to call stored procedure from codeigniter and it returns multiple results. By using result() function , i can get only one result set. In screenshot , there are three results (result1,result2,result3), how to get other two result sets??

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem  => [mydb.php file helped me out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046075/trying-to-call-stored-procedures-with-codeigniter)

Thanks to [Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806440/junaid)