# Error when calling procedures in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am calling a procedure in code igniter and when I try to call another procedure I get the following error:

> Error Number: 2014
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> call get_post_info($id)
>
> Filename: C:/Apache24/htdocs/application/models/Posts_model.php
>
> Line Number: 18

I think I need to clear the result set... not sure.

Here is my model:

```
<?php class Posts_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_post_ids($acc_id){

        $query = $this->db->query('call get_post_ids('.$this->db->escape($acc_id).')');
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function get_post($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('call get_post_info($id)');
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

In my controller:

```
$post_ids = $this->posts_model->get_post_ids(1);
foreach ($post_ids as $id){

    array_push($data, $this->posts_model->get_post($id));
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with your model function

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually run these solutions, but I found some info that might be what you look for. First of all, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now#answer-614741) about the cause of the problem.

I suppose `$query->free_result()` should solve the problem:

```
public function get_post_ids($acc_id){
    $query = $this->db->query('call get_post_ids('.$this->db->escape($acc_id).')');
    $result = $query->row_array();
    $query->free_result();
    return $result;
}
```

And in case that doesn't work, this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046075/trying-to-call-stored-procedures-with-codeigniter#answer-11139864) may be a good solution for CodeIgniter.